# Download all the files from Azure blob storage , zip it and upload the zip file in JAVA

Tags: java, azure, zip, azure-blob-storage

I want to download all the files from Azure blob storage, create a zip file out of these files and upload the zip file back to the blob storage.
As the file size can be very large, I dont want to max out the memory.
Also this operation needs to be very FAST.

JAVA SDK - azure-storage-blob 12.8.0

EDIT : Code written so far. Not sure how to proceed further with uploading pipedinputstream data parallely.

```
 String zipFileName = formFileName(exportRequest, requestId);
        final PipedOutputStream pipedOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream();
        final PipedInputStream pipedInputStream = new PipedInputStream(pipedOutputStream);

  AzureObjectStoreService objectStoreService =managedObjectStoreUtils.getObjectStoreService();

            if (filesToZip.size() > 0) {
                System.out.println("Files to zip "+ filesToZip.size());
                CompletableFuture<Boolean> zipCreationFuture = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                    LoggerHelper.logInfo(logger, "Inside createZIP file async function");
                    ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(pipedOutputStream);
                    try {
                        for (String fileName : filesToZip) {
                            try {
                                BlobClient blobClient = objectStoreService.getBlobContainerClient().getBlobClient(fileName);
                                LoggerHelper.logInfo(logger, "Adding zipEntry for file : " + fileName);
                                final ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
                                zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                                byte[] buffer;
                                ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                buffer= output.toByteArray();
                                blobClient.getBlockBlobClient().download(output);
                                int len;
                                while ((len = buffer.length) > 0) {
                                    zipOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                                }
                                zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
                            } catch (SdkClientException e) {
                                LoggerHelper.logExceptionWithMessage(logger, this.getClass().getName(), (Exception) e);
                                LoggerHelper.logError(logger, "Failed while getting s3 object");
                            }
                        }
                        zipOutputStream.finish();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        LoggerHelper.logExceptionWithMessage(logger, this.getClass().getName(), (Exception) ex);
                        LoggerHelper.logError(logger, "Creating zip file failed");
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            zipOutputStream.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                            LoggerHelper.logExceptionWithMessage(logger, this.getClass().getName(), (Exception) e);
                            LoggerHelper.logError(logger, "Failed to close the zip output stream");
                        }
                    }
                    LoggerHelper.logInfo(logger, "Completed createZIP file async function");
        //            return true;
                }).handle((o, exception) -> {
                    LoggerHelper.logExceptionWithMessage(logger, this.getClass().getName(), (Exception) exception);
                    LoggerHelper.logError(logger, "Creating zip file failed");
                    return null;
                });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question and include the code you have written so far and the issues you're running into.

Comment: @GauravMantri Have edited the question. I am using pipedinputstream and want this data to be uploaded parallely, not sure which azure blob functions support this. If not, Please suggest if there is some other way to achieve this.

Comment: @GauravMantri . anything I could check/try out?

Answer (score 1):

Was able to do it this way. Please let me know if anyone has a better approach.

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                  
                    BlobClient blobClient = objectStoreService.getBlobContainerClient().getBlobClient(zipFileName);
                    BlobOutputStream blobOutputStream = blobClient.getBlockBlobClient().getBlobOutputStream();

                     try {
                            int nextData= pipedInputStream.read();
                            while (nextData!=-1) {
                                blobOutputStream.write(nextData);
                                nextData = pipedInputStream.read();
                            }blobOutputStream.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```